# C# - Creating List Trouble

Tags: c#

In my program, I have created a class called Monsters. It is defined by four different enums: Species, Rarity, Region and Type. I am trying to create a list. Here is the code I have written:

```
public class Monsters

{
    public Enums.Species monsterName;
    public Enums.Rarity rarity;
    public Enums.Region region;
    public Enums.Type monsterType;

    public Monsters(Enums.Species monsterName, Enums.Rarity rarity, Enums.Region region, Enums.Type monsterType)
    {
        this.monsterName = monsterName;
        this.rarity = rarity;
        this.region = region;
        this.monsterType = monsterType;
    }

    public Enums.Species getmonsterName()
    {
        return monsterName;
    }

    public Enums.Rarity getrarity()
    {
        return rarity;
    }

    public Enums.Region getregion()
    {
        return region;
    }

    public Enums.Type getmonsterType()
    {
        return monsterType;
    }

    List<Monsters> startersPokemon = new List<Monsters>();
    startersPokemon.Add(Enums.Species.PIKACHU, Enums.Rarity.rare, Enums.Region.Pallet, Enums.Type.electric);

}
```

When I type the final line of code where I try to add to the list, I keep getting an error telling me it is a field being used as a type. How can I rectify this problem? If a list isn't the answer to my problem, would an array be better?

Comment: Btw.. You should use properties instead of 'get*' methods.  Also, its bad practice to name something 'Type' when not referring to an actual class

Comment: It's also a good practice to use the PascalCase formatting for method names (i.e. GetRarity instead of getrarity)

Comment: @RobertLevy Can you explain the difference of properties and get methods?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Thank you for the reminder. I usually do go with the PascalCase formatting but must have slipped my mind on this one. Made that change already.

Comment: @R1zzo23 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d(v=vs.71).aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 issues in your code.

1.**`startersPokemon`** shouldn't be declared in the **Monsters class**. It can be a class:

```
public class MonstersList
{
    List<Monsters> startersPokemon = new List<Monsters>();
    // init startersPokemon 
    public MonstersList()
    {
        // please read 2nd point.
        startersPokemon.Add(...);
    }
}
```

2.You should add `an instance of Monsters` to your list. You can change your code to :

```
startersPokemon.Add(
    new Monsters
    (
        Enums.Species.PIKACHU, 
        Enums.Rarity.rare, 
        Enums.Region.Pallet, 
        Enums.Type.electric
    )
);
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the problem is when I type startersPokemon.Add, I am getting the error "startersPokemon is a 'field' but used like a 'type' ". Do you have any pointers on how to remedy that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just sitting there in the middle of the class definition.  It needs to be inside a method which would be invoked from somewhere.  That method could be your Monsters constructor that you already have or you could create a seperate method.

```
public void Initialize() 
{
    List<Monsters> startersPokemon = new List<Monsters>();  
    startersPokemon.Add(
    new Monsters
    (
        Enums.Species.PIKACHU, 
        Enums.Rarity.rare, 
        Enums.Region.Pallet, 
        Enums.Type.electric
    )
    );
}
```